# Scraping page for product's price returns same price for all items

Tags: r, rselenium

I'm scraping a webpage for educational goals.

I'm getting these values: `producto` (product), `precio_antes` (price_before), `precio_actual` (price_now) and `marca` (brand).

I'm getting the products right but:

- `precio_antes` return S/1,399.00 for all items, when the prices are different
- `precio_actual` returns NA for all items.
- `marca` returns "lg" for all items.

**Expected output:**

```
| ecommerce | marca | producto                                 | precio_antes | precio_actual |   |
|-----------|-------|------------------------------------------|--------------|---------------|---|
| wong      | lg    | LG Smart TV 49" Full HD 49LK5400         | S/1,399.00   | S/1,299.00    |   |
| wong      | lg    | LG Smart TV 60" 4K UHD 60UK6200 ThinQ AI | S/2,599.00   | S/2,299.00    |   |
```

**Current Ouput**

```
| ecommerce | marca | producto                                 | precio_antes | precio_actual |   |
|-----------|-------|------------------------------------------|--------------|---------------|---|
| wong      | lg    | LG Smart TV 49" Full HD 49LK5400         | S/1,399.00   | NA            |   |
| wong      | lg    | LG Smart TV 60" 4K UHD 60UK6200 ThinQ AI | S/1,399.00   | NA            |   |
```

I'm using `RSelenium`, I'm thinking my CSS Selector Skills need to get better.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)



#start RSelenium


rD  <- rsDriver(port = 4570L, browser = "chrome", version = "latest", chromever = "75.0.3770.90",
                geckover = "latest", iedrver = NULL, phantomver = "2.1.1",
                verbose = TRUE, check = TRUE)



remDr <- rD[["client"]]

#navigate to your page
remDr$navigate("https://www.wong.pe/tecnologia/televisores/tv")

#scroll down 10 times, waiting for the page to load at each time
for(i in 1:10){      
  remDr$executeScript(paste("scroll(0,",i*10000,");"))
  Sys.sleep(3)    
}

#get the page html
page_source<-remDr$getPageSource()


product_info <- function(node){
  precio_antes <- html_nodes(node, 'span.product-prices__value') %>% html_text
  precio_actual <- html_nodes(node, 'span.product-prices__value product-prices__value--best-price') %>% html_text 
  marca <- html_nodes(node,"p.brand") %>% html_text
  producto <- html_nodes(node,"a.product-item__name") %>% html_text


  precio_antes <-   gsub("\\S\\/\\. ", "", precio_antes)
  precio_actual <-   gsub("\\S\\/\\. ", "", precio_actual)


  data.frame(
    ecommerce = "wong",
    marca = ifelse(length(marca)==0, NA, marca),
    producto = producto,
    precio_antes = ifelse(length(precio_antes)==0, NA, precio_antes),
    precio_actual = ifelse(length(precio_actual)==0, NA, precio_actual), 
    stringsAsFactors=F
  )


}



doc <- read_html(iconv(page_source[[1]]), to="UTF-8") %>% 
  html_nodes("div.category-shelf-wrapper")



wong_tvs <- lapply(doc, product_info) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

**Bonus:**

I'm getting spanish characters not in the right way, even when I'm using:

```
LG Control Remoto MÃ¡gico AN-MR18BA #Should be Mágico

doc <- read_html(iconv(page_source[[1]]), to="UTF-8") %>% 
  html_nodes("div.category-shelf-wrapper")
```

**Why?**

Comment: I'd strongly recommend *not* combining multiple questions. The "bonus" question seems much simpler than the rest---I bet if you post that as a separate question, you'll get an answer very quickly. But leaving it at the bottom of the big question, you hide it and discourage anyone from answering unless they can answer the big question too.

Comment: could you ellaborate a bit more on the expected output. I partly understand the negative example. A positive one would be great, thanks!

Comment: @BigDataScientist please, see the changes in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edit adds a great specification, thanks!

I assume you want to track missing elements again with `NA` in the output.
Following that assumption i would, similar to the other question, go for the parent element again.

The parent element can be located, e.g. by xpath: `/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li/div/div[@class = 'product-item__bottom']`.

After that you just have to split the results in the desired format.

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver() 
remDr <- rD$client

url = "https://www.wong.pe/tecnologia/televisores"
remDr$navigate(url)

productElems = remDr$findElements(
  using = "xpath", 
  value = "/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li/div/div[@class = 'product-item__bottom']"
)

productInfoRaw = sapply(
  X = productElems, 
  FUN = function(elem) elem$getElementText()
)

splittedRaw = sapply(productInfoRaw, strsplit, split = "\n")
splitted = lapply(splittedRaw, function(split){
  if(length(split) == 5 &  "Online" %in% split){
    split[7] = split[4]
    split[4] = NA
  }
  return(split)
})

infos = data.frame(
  ecommerce = "wong",
  marca = sapply(splitted, "[", 2),
  producto = sapply(splitted, "[", 1),
  precio_antes = sapply(splitted, "[", 4),
  precio_actual = sapply(splitted, "[", 7)
)
head(infos)
```

**Output:**

```
> head(infos)
  ecommerce   marca                                 producto precio_antes precio_actual
1      wong      LG         LG Smart TV 49" Full HD 49LK5400   S/1,399.00    S/1,299.00
2      wong      LG LG Smart TV 60" 4K UHD 60UK6200 ThinQ AI   S/2,599.00    S/2,299.00
3      wong      LG       LG Control Remoto Mágico AN-MR18BA         <NA>      S/199.00
4      wong     AOC    AOC Smart TV 32'' HD LE32S5970S Linux     S/799.00      S/599.00
5      wong      LG             LG Smart TV 43" FHD 43LK5400   S/1,199.00      S/999.00
6      wong HISENSE  Hisense Televisor LED 32'' HD H3218H4IP   S/1,299.00      S/499.00
```

Comment: Why did you need to set `remDr$setWindowSize(2900, 3200)`?

Comment: that might actually be redundant. Sometimes you have to adjust the screensize to see all elements. First i didnt find some elements so i included it, but its probably redundant here.

Comment: Ok, maybe would be a good idea to put in your answer the call to the `rsDriver`, so people could reproduce this answer in future cases.

Comment: I'm seeing an error with the third row, where there is a NA value, as S/199.00 should be in `precio_actual` column, and NA in `precio_antes` (as we don't know what was the price before). How could be handle these cases?

Comment: as the grace period for bounty ends soon: Is the code working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is slow and should only be used as a last resort. In this case it's unnecessary since the catalogue API is exposed. The API also offers richer, well-structured data. It's possible to request 50 items at a time, so you can increment through 0, 50, etc. until the total length of the returned contents is < 50, then you can pull the required information by name and/or integer position.

The numbers 1000144 and 1000098 in the URL refer to department and category and can be extracted from a `script` node in the HTML of https://www.wong.pe/tecnologia/televisores/tv. I didn't do that here to keep things simple, but it is possible if you want a more adaptable scraper.

Instead of `glue` you can also use `paste0`. Instead of `map_df` you can use `lapply` and then bind the rows using `do.call` and `rbind`. Instead of `bind_cols` you can use `cbind` with `as.data.frame`. I like these functions because they simplify things, avoid type coercion issues, and generally improve the readability of my code, but there's nothing to keep you from using base R functions.

For the sake of simplicity I've kept the original variable names. You can change them with `names(tvs_df) <- …` or after the call to `map_df` with `set_names(…)`, i.e. `map_df(…) %>% set_names(…)`:

```r
library(httr)   # for `GET`
library(glue)   # for `glue`, which allows cleaner syntax than `paste0`
library(purrr)  # for `map_df` to map over list and return as dataframe
library(dplyr)  # for `bind_cols`

i <- 0
cont_list <- list()

# Send requests and append data `cont_list` until fewer than 50 items returned.
repeat {
    url <- glue("https://www.wong.pe/api/catalog_system/pub/products/search/",
                "?&fq=C:/1000144/1000098/&_from={i}&_to={i + 49}")
    cont <- content(GET(url))
    cont_list <- c(cont_list, cont)
    if (length(cont) < 50) break
    i <- i + 50
}

# Names of desired data.
datl <- list(l1 = c("brand", "productName"),
             l2 = c("Price", "ListPrice", "AvailableQuantity"))

# Extract data 
tvs_df <- map_df(cont_list,
                 ~ bind_cols(source = "wong.pe", .[datl$l1],
                             .$items[[1]]$sellers[[1]]$commertialOffer[datl$l2]))
```

Which returns:

```r
# A tibble: 54 x 6
   source  brand     productName                                 Price ListPrice AvailableQuantity
   <chr>   <chr>     <chr>                                       <dbl>     <dbl>             <int>
 1 wong.pe LG        "LG Smart TV 49\" Full HD 49LK5400"          1299      1399               276
 2 wong.pe LG        "LG Smart TV 60\" 4K UHD 60UK6200 ThinQ AI"  2299      2599                18
 3 wong.pe LG        LG Control Remoto Mágico AN-MR18BA            199       199                37
 4 wong.pe AOC       AOC Smart TV 32'' HD LE32S5970S Linux         599       799                90
 5 wong.pe LG        "LG Smart TV 43\" FHD 43LK5400"               999      1199               303
 6 wong.pe Hisense   Hisense Televisor LED 32'' HD H3218H4IP       499      1299                22
 7 wong.pe LG        "LG Smart TV 55\" 4K UHD 55UK6200 ThinQ AI"  1799      2199                31
 8 wong.pe Panasonic Panasonic Smart TV Viera 32'' HD 32FS500      799       999                 4
 9 wong.pe AOC       AOC Smart TV 55'' 4K UHD 55U7970 Linux       1299      2499                 3
10 wong.pe AOC       AOC Televisor LED 32'' HD 32M1370             499       699                 4
# … with 44 more rows
```

Comment: how do you detect when the `API` is exposed in a page? For example, would you mind taking a look on these pages `https://www.linio.com.pe/` and `https://www.lacuracao.pe/`?

Comment: ty. it works but prefer BigDataScientist method because I know RSelenium better.